# Do I have to follow iOS Data storage guidelines even when iCloud is not enabled for my app

Tags: ios, app-store, icloud, appstore-approval, data-storage

I have created an app ID that does not enable iCloud.  But does that mean that I have to follow iOS Data Storage Guidelines to get my app approved for appstore?
I am using App's Documents Folder to store large files, such as Photos.
I have already uploaded my app on the appstore and it is Waiting for Review. I am worried it might get rejected. Please help!

Comment: Long answer - as Jessedc said, Yes you have to. And be calm, you can wait fix it and a rejection is reversible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  It's because everything in the user directory, with the exception of tmp and Library/cache directories, is backed up by default and Apple doesn't want content that is easily regenerated/re-downloaded to be copied into the cloud.

If you can show that your large files are "user generated content", then it should be able to get approved as is.   Otherwise you can use the "do not backup" flag to mark the files or directories that hold your content.